# get selected value from dropdownlist with jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I'm new with this jquery dialog in asp.net. I'm trying to get the selected value from dropdownlist which is open in jquery dialog. First user will click a button and a dialog will show up. In the dialog, user will select item in the dropdownlist and when the user click Ok, the update query will execute based on selected value from the dropdownlist. The problem is, there is no change in my table when user click Ok. This is the code I have. Thanks in advance

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    Ok: function () {
                        $("[id*=btnOKStatus]").click();
                    },
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    };
</script>

xml
   <asp:ImageButton ID="btnUpdateStatus" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="~/images/btnUpdateStatus.png" Height="40px" Width="50px" 
    Style="vertical-align: middle;" BorderStyle="None" OnClick="btnShowPopup_Click" />``

 <div id="dialog" style="display: none">
<asp:Label ID="lblDialog" runat="server" Text="Sila pilih status: "></asp:Label><br /><asp:DropDownList
    ID="ddlStatus" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Pending</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Complete</asp:ListItem>    </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
       <asp:Button ID="btnOKStatus" runat="server" Text="Button" style =                        
      "display:none" OnClick = "btnOKStatus_Click" />
```

VB

```
Protected Sub btnShowPopup_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateStatus.Click
    Dim message As String = ""
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", True)
End Sub

Protected Sub btnOKStatus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Using mysqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        mysqlConnection.Open()

        queryStr = "UPDATE `order` SET status=@status WHERE ID=@orderID"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(queryStr, mysqlConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", Page.Request.QueryString("orderID").ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ddlStatus.SelectedValue)
        Dim num As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If num > 0 Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Success!')", True)
        Else
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Fail')", True)
        End If
        mysqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following selector will return the selected value.

```
$('#ddlStatus > li:selected').val()
```

This appears to be more of an ASP.Net question, however. If you want to get the selected value of your dropdownlist in your VB.Net code, you can use the ID for your dropdownlist and access the dropdownlist in your VB.net code,

```
ddlStatus.SelectedValue
```

Try changing this

```
Protected Sub btnOKStatus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Using mysqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        mysqlConnection.Open()

        queryStr = "UPDATE `order` SET status=@status WHERE ID=@orderID"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(queryStr, mysqlConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", Page.Request.QueryString("orderID").ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ddlStatus.SelectedValue)
        Dim num As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If num > 0 Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Success!')", True)
        Else
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Fail')", True)
        End If
        mysqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

to this:

```
Protected Sub btnOKStatus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Page.IsPostBack = False Then
    Using mysqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(connStr)
        mysqlConnection.Open()

        queryStr = "UPDATE `order` SET status=@status WHERE ID=@orderID"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(queryStr, mysqlConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderID", Page.Request.QueryString("orderID").ToString())
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ddlStatus.SelectedValue)
        Dim num As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        If num > 0 Then
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Success!')", True)
        Else
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.[GetType](), "key", "alert('Fail')", True)
        End If
        mysqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for response. I did access it in my VB.net code, but it turn out to update using first selected value..in this case "New"

Comment: Oh i see it in your code. You're using SelectedValue like a method with "()" -- it's a property. Try using ddlStatus.SelectedValue to see if it works.

Comment: did what you said.. but it still updating using the value of first item in dropdownlist eventhough i chose second item

Comment: try ddlStatus.SelectedIndex instead. I remember having similar issues with this. You should get a number back that corresponds to the index of the list item

Comment: it could be that there is no value assigned by default, which is kind of weird. There is also the SelectedItem property: ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Text and ddlStatus.SelectedItem.Value

Comment: thanks. i tried ur way and the problem is still there

Comment: Your code may be getting reset during the postback, try wrapping your OK click event code inside of an if statement like this: if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{

    // Your binding code here ...

}

Comment: sorry.. i don't get it. Can you show the coding please?

Comment: OK- edited the code. Try the second one there with the If statement using Page.IsPostBack

Answer (score 0):

It's too late but I am posting the answer for those who are facing similar issue (as mentioned in the title of the question) (and for those who are not using ASP.net)
`var selectedItemText = $("#myselect option:selected" ).text();
 var selectedItemCode = $("#myselect option:selected" ).val();`